How to remove a bar-mounted junction box from the ceiling?
I’m guessing the metal rod going through the box is screwed into the joists. Is there good way to remove this while doing the least amount of damage to the ceiling? I would like to remove the box, remove the wires and patch the hole.


Welcome. Please take the [tour].

if a bar, it was mounted from above

Note that when you say "remove the wires", you can't just bury the wires in the ceiling.  You would need to completely remove them, or at least disconnect them from the previous junction box cap them off in the previous box, and note in the previous junction box that they're abandoned, so someone in the future doesn't try and reconnect them.

The switch loop plus the red wires might mean this older light box was on circuit with three way switches.  Removing the light/box without having another way to light room might be against code.  Code requires switches at each entrance to control a light, even if just a desk lamp on a switched receptacle/outlet.

Those colors don't make any sense, what's the red wire doing?

A reciprocating ("saws-all") saw blade can be slid into the gap between the box and the drywall so that it cuts the bar above the box. These can get hot too of course, but not so hot as an abrasive cutter and they don't throw yellow-hot glowing sparks.
Cutting blind is a bit dangerous as you have no idea what cables or other things you may also cut through. With some skill one could use the recip saw to cut away a section of the junction box with only about 1" hazard zone beyond the box walls.
The focus on the box might be misplaced: it's not obvious how one could properly remove the wires from the building through just a small octagon hole. Live wires can't be abandoned in the structure; before abandonment both ends must be permanently disconnected.

OP can pop the knock outs out and might see if any nasties near the cuts.

Also, since the hole will ostensibly be patched (burying wires notwithstanding) there's no real reason not to simply enlarge the hole for saw access.  A (slightly) bigger hole isn't any harder to patch than a hole the size of the box.  Enlarging the hole would give better access, and also enable one to see where the wires are.

disconnect all the wires at both ends of each,
confirm that you aren't missing power anywhere else
with the wires disconnected cut the wires off where they enter the box, so they won'y accidentally get connected to something.
Then jack the box up into the ceiling until the bar bends or lets go, then patch the hole.

I'm not familiar with that exact box, but the slots in the box were obviously pressed outward so the bar can pass through them. The question is whether they're continuous or just tabs.
If they're tabs, jam a flat screwdriver in there and try to bend them upward to release the bar.
If not, you'll have to cut either the tabs or the bar. How you do that depends on available tools. An oscillating saw might work with a carbide-tipped blade.  Various abrasive grinding tools could work. Just be careful not to start a fire in your attic.
